# How can I process options using Perl in -n or -p mode?

Tags: perl, command-line-interface

When running `perl -n` or `perl -p`, each command line argument is taken as a file to be opened and processed line by line. If you want to pass command line switches to that script, how can I do that?

Comment: In a `BEGIN` block. Normally you'd use `Getopt::Std` or `Getopt::Long`. There's also perl's `-s` option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three primary ways of passing information to Perl without using STDIN or external storage.

- Arguments

  When using `-n` or `-p`, extract the arguments in the `BEGIN` block.

  ```bash
  perl -ne'BEGIN { ($x,$y)=splice(@ARGV,0,2) } f($x,$y)' -- "$x" "$y" ...
  ```
- Command-line options

  In a full program, you'd use [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long), but [`perl -s`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) will do fine here.

  ```bash
  perl -sne'f($x,$y)' -- -x="$x" -y="$y" -- ...
  ```
- Environment variables

  ```bash
  X="$x" Y="$y" perl -ne'f($ENV{X},$ENV{Y})' -- ...
  ```

Comment: And now I see why I was having such a hard time. Check this out:


`perl -ne 'BEGIN{some; code; that; checks for -n;} per; line; code;' -n file1 file2`


See my mistake? I unconsciously assumed that once I Perl processed the -e, all other args were for my program. Not so: that -n was swallowed by Perl. And, technically, so are the filenames.  


From your second paragraph, it hit me that I had to add -- to stop option processing by Perl. Then I can process ARGV to my heart's content in the BEGIN block and anything left will be left to -p or-n handling.


Thank you @ikegami

Answer (score -1):

Here is a short example program (name it `t.pl`), how you can do it:

```
#!/bin/perl
use Getopt::Std;

BEGIN {
  my %opts;
  getopts('p', \%opts);
  $prefix = defined($opts{'p'}) ? 'prefix -> ' : '';
}

print $prefix, $_;
```

Call it like that:

```
perl -n t.pl file1 file2 file3
```

or (will add a prefix to every line):

```
perl -n t.pl -p file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: There really is no case where new code should use ::Std.  Always start with Getopt::Long

Comment: Yes, using long options is more up to date. You can easily adapt and improve. This is only for demonstration.

Comment: even just using short options, you should use Getopt::Long; it's no more difficult.