# How do I select specific columns with the perl -lane command line?

Tags: shell, perl

The command line below works for me

```
perl -F'\t' -lane'print join ",", @F[1,2]' inputfile
```

BUT I want to pass a variable list of columns, not necessarily columns 1 and 2 as specified in `@F[1,2]`.

For example, based on the total number of columns of the inputfile, I would like to select a random subset `"$random-columns"` and pass it to `@F[$random-columns]`.

How do I do that?

I tried to first generate a columnList of 5 random column numbers between 1 and 50:

```
columnList=()
for (( i = 0; i <= 5-1; ++i ))
do
    (( randCol = ($RANDOM % 50) + 1 ))
    columnList[i]=$randCol
done
```

Then I did the following to insert the comma:

```
cols_new=$(IFS=,; echo "${columnList[*]}")
```

and tried to pass it to the perl command line as below (didn't work):

```
perl -F'\t' -lane'print join ",", @F[$cols_new]' inputfile
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I process options using Perl in -n or -p mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53524699/589924)?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`rand`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html).

Five random number from 0 to 50:

```
@randoms = map {int(rand(50))} 1..5;
```

In your one-liner:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join ",", @F[map {int(rand(50))} 1..5]' inputfile
```

To use the same random column indexes for each line, use a `BEGIN` block that only executes once at the start of the program:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'BEGIN {@rand = map {int(rand(50))} 1..5]}; print join ",", @F[@rand]' inputfile
```

Comment: that will get a different set of random columns for each input line, a very different thing

Comment: `int(rand(50))` creates a random integer from 0 to 49, not 0 to 50. Also, `int()` is not needed here since the numbers are for array indices and Perl automatically "ints" those.

Comment: @ysth. If we need the same random columns for each line, just:

`perl -F'\t' -lane '@i=map rand(1+$#F), 1..5 if not @i; print join ",", @F[@i]' inputfile`.

Here `1+$#F` is used instead of 50 since that allows for any number of fields the file happens to have on its first line.

Comment: @KjetilS. `1+$#F` better written as `@F`.

Comment: @melpomene ← Agree, but I think `0+@F` is even more readable. (And allowing for some future rand() to have more than one parameter, althou that's very unlikely)

Comment: @KjetilS. That would change the operator precedence of `rand`, so it'll never happen.

Comment: @ysth True. Edited to set the randos in a `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 1):

Your `perl -e'...$cols_new...'` is using single shell quotes, so the shell is not interpolating the variable.

While you can use interpolation or a command line argument to get information from the shell to a perl oneliner, often an environment variable is less troublesome:

```
export cols_new=1,2
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join ",", @F[split /,/, $ENV{cols_new}]' inputfile
```

Comment: Or in the some simple cases (like this one) just replace the two `'` with `"` and `","` with `'"'` or `q(,)`. As in `perl -F'\t' -lane "print join q(,), @F[split /,/, $cols_new]" inputfile`. But I think it's better to use perl to generate the array of random numbers like in @beasy 's answer.

Comment: @KjetilS.  except that the question was "I want to pass a variable list of columns".  the bit about random columns was only "For example"

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the random number generation in Perl:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'BEGIN { @cols = map int(rand 50) + 1, 1 .. 5 } print join ",", @F[@cols]' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much !!
I solved the problem following your suggestions (see below):

- Randomly selects $extractColumnCount columns from the range 2-$fileColumnCount,
  sort them and place them in $cols_new_temp

## cols_new_temp=$(echo $(shuf -i 2-$fileColumnCount -n $extractColumnCount | sort -n))

## echo $cols_new_temp

- Here I add commas to separate the array of column labels and place it in $cols_new

## cols_new=$(echo $cols_new_temp | sed 's/ /,/g')

## echo $cols_new

- This Perl oneliner retrieves a subset of pre-specified randomly-selected columns ($cols_new) from the file specified in $file1, adding the first column and the output column. The resulting file is then saved as $file2

## output_col=1

## time perl -F',' -lane "print join q(,), @F[split "," $output_col,$cols_new]"  $file1  > $file2