# change of ip address using perl or sed

Tags: bash, perl, ksh

I've an input file that consists of IP Address and subnet masks. As an example,

```
1.example.com,10.135.10.111,255.255.255.0,some comment
2.example.com,10.135.10.112,255.255.255.0,some comment
3.example.com,10.135.10.113,255.255.255.0,some comment
4.example.com,10.135.10.11,255.255.255.0, some comment
10.135.10.111 A 
10.135.10.112 A
10.135.10.113 A
10.135.10.11  A
```

I loop the IP address in my bash script and when using the `perl` or `sed` command all `.11` gets changed. As an example:

```perl
inputip=10.135.10.11
newip=10.135.10.77

perl -i -e 's/$inputip/$newip/g' inputfile
```

OR

```bash
sed -e "s/$inputip/$newip/g" inputfile
```

The problem is all instance of `.11` gets changed. so the above record of `10.135.10.111` is changed to `10.135.10.771`, `.772`, `.773`, `.77`

Note: this line `10.135.10.11  A` is not necessarily the last line, it's anywhere in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
$ cat inputfile
1.example.com,10.135.10.111,255.255.255.0,some comment
2.example.com,10.135.10.112,255.255.255.0,some comment
3.example.com,10.135.10.113,255.255.255.0,some comment
4.example.com,10.135.10.11,255.255.255.0, some comment
4.example.com,210.135.10.11,255.255.255.0, some comment
10.135.10.111 A
10.135.10.112 A
10.135.10.113 A
10.135.10.11  A
210.135.10.11 A
```

With `GNU sed` and word boundary sequences (`\<` / `\>`):

```
$ inputip=10.135.10.11
$ newip=10.135.10.77
$ sed "s/\<$inputip\>/$newip/g" inputfile
1.example.com,10.135.10.111,255.255.255.0,some comment
2.example.com,10.135.10.112,255.255.255.0,some comment
3.example.com,10.135.10.113,255.255.255.0,some comment
4.example.com,10.135.10.77,255.255.255.0, some comment
4.example.com,210.135.10.11,255.255.255.0, some comment
10.135.10.111 A
10.135.10.112 A
10.135.10.113 A
10.135.10.77  A
210.135.10.11 A
```

If this does not work then OP is likely not using `GNU sed`; in this case we'd need to know what version of `sed` is in use (eg, `sed --version`).

Comment: Thank you Markp-fuso as well as Hatless for the quick response and answers. Both solution works!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are four problems with the Perl version.

- You're missing `-p`.
- You expected Perl to use the shell variables `$inputip` and `$newip`, but those are only found in the shell process. There's a number of ways to pass values to `perl`, as you can see in [How can I process options using Perl in -n or -p mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53524699/589924).
- There's also a code injection bug, where `.` isn't matched literally.
- There's an anchoring problem, where you accidentally modify IP addresses you don't want to change. For example, you will corrupt `210.135.10.11` when trying to change `10.135.10.11`.

Fixed:

```bash
perl -i -spe's/\b\Q$o\E\b/$n/g' -- -o="$inputip" -n="$newip" inputfile
```

Comment: Nice use of `-s` :)