# How can I replace everything after a string using Bash?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a Perl script that uses some local variables as per below:

```perl
my $cool_variable="Initial value";
COOLVAR="Initial value for COOLVAR"
```

I would like to replace the content between the quotes using a bash script.

I got it to work for a non-variable like below:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
dummy_var="Replaced value"
sed -i -r "s#^(COOLVAR=).*#\1$dummy_var#" perlscript.pl
```

But if I replace it with cool_variable or $cool_variable:

```bash
sed -i -r "s#^($cool_variable=).*#\1$dummy_var#" perlscript.pl
```

It does not work..

Comment: Rather than editing the perl script, why not have it read the necessary value from a configuration file, which could be as simple as just a text file containing the desired text. Then the Perl script merely needs to read the contents of the file to initialize `COOLVAR`.

Comment: What is this supposed to be in your Perl code: `COOLVAR="Initial value for COOLVAR"`. If I try to run that code I get `Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment` compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

The are multiple code injection bugs in that snippet. You shouldn't be generating code from the shell or sed.

---

Say you have

```bash
var=COOLVAR
val=coolval
```

As per [How can I process options using Perl in -n or -p mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53524699/589924), you can use any of

```bash
perl -spe's{^$var=\K.*}{"\Q$val\E";};' -- -var="$var" -val="$val" perlscript.pl
```

```bash
var=var val=val perl -pe's{^$ENV{var}=\K.*}{"\Q$ENV{val}\E";};' perlscript.pl
```

```bash
export var
export val
perl -pe's{^$ENV{var}=\K.*}{"\Q$ENV{val}\E";};' perlscript.pl
```

to transform

```perl
COOLVAR="dummy";
HOTVAR="dummy";
```

into

```perl
COOLVAR="coolvar";
HOTVAR="dummy";
```

The values are passed to the program using arguments to avoid injecting them into the fixer, and the fixer uses Perl's `quotemeta` (aka \Q..\E) to quote special characters.

Note that `$var` is assumed to be a valid identifier. No validation checks are performed. This program is absolutely unsafe using untrusted input.

Use `-i` to modify the file in place.