# How to expand a shell variable in a Perl command

Tags: shell, perl

I want to replace the string using a shell variable.

```
today =`date '+%Y%m%d'`

perl -p -i -e 's/file"20221212"/file="${today}"/g'
```

The expectation is `file="20221215"`.
But it failed, result is `file=""`.

How to escape this case？

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How can I process options using Perl in -n or -p mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53524699/589924)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is shell quoting. Using single quotes, `'`, to delimit the Perl code disables all variable expansion. You need to use double quotes, `"`, to get variable expansion.

Using shell without any Perl to illustrate the issue

```
today=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
echo 'today is $today'
```

will output this -- with no expansion of `$today`

```
today is $today
```

now with double quotes

```
today=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
echo "today is $today"
```

outputs this -- `$today` has been expanded.

```
today is 20221215
```

Applying that to your code (I've removed the `-i` option to make it easier to see the results) and escaped all double quotes in the perl code with `\"`

```
echo 'file"20221212"' >input.txt
perl -p  -e "s/file\"20221212\"/file=\"${today}\"/g" input.txt
```

gives

```
file="20221215"
```

Comment: I like to tell people that the -e argument is just a string. Whatever your shell does to make that string and pass it on is what you have to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here I am giving you the hint how it should be:

I cannot reproduce the issue from your code.

```
#!/bin/sh
today=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
echo "today:$today"

file="input.txt";

perl -pi -e 's/file20221212/file='${today}'/g' $file
```

where `input.txt` contains:

```
file20221212
```

Answer (score 1):

The two earlier answers are [horrible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). Don't generate Perl code from the shell.

This question was already asked and answered here: [How can I process options using Perl in -n or -p mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53524699/589924)

It provides three solution, including

```bash
perl -spe's/file\K"20221212"/="$today"/g' -- -today="$today"
```

```bash
TODAY="$today" perl -pe's/file\K"20221212"/="$ENV{today}"/g'
```

---

Alternatively, you could also avoid `date` and passing a value entirely.

```bash
perl -MPOSIX -pe'
   BEGIN { $today = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime }
   s/file\K"20221212"/="$today"/g
'
```