# Perl one-liner: capture groups in a substitution being interpreted as octal

Tags: bash, perl

Assume that I have a file that contains the text `foo_bar_baz`, and I want to replace it with `foo_bar_1234` (this is a simplified version of a more complex issue).

First try:

```
 $ echo "foo_bar_baz" > testfile
 $ perl -pi -e "s/(foo_)(bar_).*/\1\2 1234/" testfile
 $ cat testfile
 foo_bar_ 1234
```

So, I just need to get rid of the space before the `1234`. The obvious answer is

```
 $ perl -pi -e "s/(foo_)(bar_).*/\1\21234/" testfile
```

...but this doesn't work. The substitution contains the octal character `\212` in it. How do I fix this? The octal issue is covered briefly [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups), but I seem to have missed the answer. The doc states that "Perl resolves this ambiguity by interpreting \10 as a backreference only if at least 10 left parentheses have opened before it", which clearly isn't the case here. Additionally, using `\g2` or `\g{2}` doesn't fix the problem.

I'm on Perl 5.34.0, bash 5.1.16.

**EDIT**

This question was rolled back to rev 3 by another user, without any understanding of the question. The original question only made sense in the context of this being a Perl one-liner, executed from a bash script; the problem is/was simply the differing interpretation of variable expansion between Bash and Perl, and the use of single or double quotes. I don't have 2K rep so I can't roll the erroneous edit.

Comment: Using `warnings` should produce a warning saying something like "\1 better written as $1 at ...". Always use `warnings` and fix all of the warnings it produces.

Comment: Updating your question to pile on new requirements is not really advisable after you have received good answers. Probably (roll back your latest edit and) accept the answer you got, then ask a new question with your _actual_ requirements if you still need help.

Comment: @tripleee: it wasn't a new requirement. The question had a bash tag, which someone removed, made it clear that it was simplified  code, and included the text `perl -pi -e`, so it was a question about a one-liner in bash. After reading a good answer for a non-bash situation I realised that the question should have been clearer, and so clarified it.

Comment: chepner's answer from 14 hours ago clearly and succinctly answers the question you originally asked. Again, if that's not what you meant, that doesn't mean the answer is wrong; it means you should have asked a different question. Going back now and editing it looks like chepner didn't understand what you were asking, which is doing them and future readers a disservice, at minimum by making things more confusing, and at worst misleading people to disregard a good answer.

Comment: Don't replace the question with a completely different one after it's answered. Post a new question if you have a new question. Your new question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53524699/589924)

Answer (score 6):

The replacement text should use `$1` in place of `\1` for the contents of a  capture group. Like any other parameter expansion, you can delimit the name of the parameter with `{...}`.

```
perl -pi -e 's/(foo_)(bar_).*/$1${2}1234/' testfile
```

(Note the use of single quotes to simplify escaping the `$1` and `$2` to avoid shell interpolation of each before Perl sees the script to execute.)

If you need to expand a parameter to create the Perl script, explicitly escape the `$`s intended to be interpreted by Perl, not the shell. For example,

```
foo=1234
perl -pi -e "s/(foo_)(bar_).*/\$1\${2}$foo/" testfile
```

Better yet, though, don't try to generate the Perl script using shell interpolation. Pass the value of `foo` as an argument to a static script.

```
# The use of the -p option complicates matters.
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN { $x = shift @ARGV } s/(foo_)(bar_).*/$1${2}$x/' testfile "$foo"
```

Comment: I should have added more detail to my original post... :\  Unfortunately, `1234` is actually a shell variable, so I can't use single quotes, or name the groups with a `$`. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Yes, I focused on "how to enable the injection bug" before explaining how to avoid it :)

Comment: I did notice the issue with `-p` while testing, but was wondering if it had to do with my using a here string rather than a file (and dropping `-i` from the test). I was expecting an option like `bash`'s `-s` option, but couldn't find one. (It's been a while since I've written Perl, if it's not obvious :) )

Comment: Wondering how I remembered how `slice` worked, but forgot `shift` existed...

Comment: I think you mean `splice`, which works identically to 4-operand `substr` but for arrays.

Comment: I'm going to stop talking now :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of capturing and putting back the matches, you can just match and use `\K` escape sequence to "keep" the matches to the left:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/foo_bar_\K.*/1234/' testfile
```

`\K` requires perl version 5.10.0 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of random typing, I think I've found an "answer", but I don't like it. The original code in the question works *if* you can guarantee that the first character of the variable to be substituted is not a digit (so `key=abcd` works, but `key=1bcd` doesn't).

If you don't know in advance what the first character of the variable will be, then you have to export and read the variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "foo_bar_baz" > testfile
export key=1235
perl -pi -e 's/(foo_)(bar_).*/$1$2$ENV{key}/' testfile
cat testfile
```

This appears to be entirely contrary to the docs [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups), because there are only 2 capture groups here, so there is no possibility of ambiguities (`\21234` could not possibly be a capture group).

This makes me think that using Perl one-liners for substitutions in bash scripts is not a good idea. I've already found one of my old scripts that wasn't tested with digits and fails. In future, I think I'll be using bash-native substitutions.

Comment: Again, this is why Perl urges you to use `$` instead of `\ ` for backreferences. It's true that the Perl parser _could_ try to resolve things and accept syntax like `\234` but, welp, it doesn't, and it's not clear why it should.

Comment: @tripleee: which isn't possible in a one-liner in a bash script.

Comment: Why do you say that? Your solution is a Perl one-liner in a Bash script. But a simpler solution is to use "seesaw quoting"; `perl -pe 's/(foo_)(bar_).*/$1$2'"$key/"` (provided `$key` does not contain any Perl regex metacharacters or slashes; but then your solution is better in that it doesn't have that requirement). Equivalently, use double quotes, and add backslash escapes where necessary: `perl -pi "s/(foo_)(bar_).*/\$1\$2$key/"`

Comment: There are no "bash native" substitutions, other than the trivial (but needlessly slow) `while read -r line; do echo "${line//foo_bar_*/foo_bar_$key}"; done`

Comment: @tripleee: I'm not sure I understand your point. This answer is a complex bodge, because it has to retrieve the bash expansion via an envvar. If the variable is not numeric, I can get both Perl and Bash vars without any added complexity; use double quotes, `\` for Perl, and `$` for bash, and everything just works.

Comment: @tripleee: "but [...] it doesn't, and it's not clear why it should" - well, maybe because the docs at perl.org, which I referenced twice, explicitly state that "*\10 could mean either the tenth capture group, or the character whose ordinal in octal is 010 (a backspace in ASCII). Perl resolves this ambiguity by interpreting \10 as a backreference only if at least 10 left parentheses have opened before it*"?

Comment: Not sure which part you are responding to. `key="value" perl -pi 's/(foo_)(bar_).*/$1$2$env{"key"}/'` would be a one-liner _and_ avoid the silly backslashed backrefs.

Answer (score -1):

Not clear what form your starting phrase will always take, but assuming your use of '_' to separate things, would this work?

```
#!/bin/bash
key=_1234
echo "foo_bar_baz" > testfile
perl -pi -e "s/(foo_)(bar)_.*/\1\2$key/" testfile
cat testfile
# foo_bar_1234
```

This eliminates your character problem by putting a '_' at the start of the replacement bit, so your captures won't confuse perl.

Comment: This has a [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bug.

Comment: @ikegami: To be sure I understand, does this have a code injection bug different from the OP's script?