# Want to match a string exactly, despite variants, and remove only that string

Tags: string, language-agnostic

I have the need to remove a specific, *exact* string from a file. This is being utilized as part of a clean-up process that I'm implementing.  The problem is, there are variants that are similar to, but not exactly the same as the specially *exact* string that I want to remove.

For example, here is a sample of the file "sample":

```
tmp2
tmp3
tmp0
tmp1
tmp3
tmp3
tmp3
tmp1.1
tmp3
tmp2
tmp3
tmp1.2
tmp4
```

I want to remove only "tmp1", not "tmp1.1" or "tmp1.2".

I am using a single-lined Perl command:

```
perl -i -nle 'print if !/tmp1/' ./sample
```

Obviously, the single-lined script isn't cutting.  Sure, it's removing "tmp1", but, it's Aalso removing "tmp1.1" and "tmp1.2" as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to match the string only if it's the whole line or if it's a space-separated field in a line, or could be a substring of another string or what? Do you want to remove the string or the line containing the string or what?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the string based upon it being followed by whitespace (horizontal such as ` ` space or vertical such as `\n` newline)? And is this ASCII-only text or will you be cleaning-up Unicode?

Comment: do you know upfront that you want to remove `tmp1`, or do you need to (programmatically) find any `tmpN.M` strings, strip off the `.M` and then remove the standalone `tmpN` entry(s)?  for example, if you add a line with `tmp3.1` would you also need to remove all lines with the string `tmp3`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use anchors. `^` for beginning of line, and `$` for end of line.

```
$ perl -i -nle 'print if !/^tmp1$/' ./sample
```

Comment: YES!!!!  That did the trick!!!  Here's also part of the problem - I'm writing a bash script using the above single-lined entry on Apple's macOS.  PLEASE don't shoot me - I use my Mac for initial code development using an IDE, test it, then upload on the target LINUX system. I intend to use it on a Debian-based LINUX system.  I suspect that there may be subtle differences as I've had problems in the past with similar single-lined entry scripts.

Comment: If you have further issues, you can always come back and ask a new question. There should not be too many issues with this short oneliner. Although if you import files between mac and linux, you may get some issues with line endings. Or perhaps they both use debian, so it is no longer an issue, that's not my field of expertise. :)

Comment: Um...and I feel embarrassed to ask this again, but... if "tmp1" were variable as: `perl -i -nle "print if !/${STRING}/" $FILENAME` whereas `${STRING}` is what I'm changing with file `$FILENAME`, what would `$STRING` be within the perl one-liner?

Comment: @infracritical Don't generate shell code from the shell. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53524699/589924) for ways of passing data to Perl.

Comment: @infracritical If you have a new question, post it as a new question, that is the best way to get answers. Using shell variables is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box, here's a full-line string comparison that'll remove the line that matches that string:

```
$ awk '$0 != "tmp1"' sample
tmp2
tmp3
tmp0
tmp3
tmp3
tmp3
tmp1.1
tmp3
tmp2
tmp3
tmp1.2
tmp4
```

or using a variable:

```
$ awk -v str='tmp1' '$0 != str' sample
tmp2
tmp3
tmp0
tmp3
tmp3
tmp3
tmp1.1
tmp3
tmp2
tmp3
tmp1.2
tmp4
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for more info on that.

Note that the above is doing a literal string comparison so it'll work even if your target string contains regexp metacharacters, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
foo.bar1
foo.bar
foo bar
```

```
$ awk '$0 != "foo.bar"' file
foo.bar1
foo bar
```

Comment: Now substitute "foo.bar" with a bash script variable $CHK which contains the value 'foo.bar'.  Doesn't work.  I get `awk: illegal filed $(), name "CHK"`

Comment: If I use your "foo.bar" example, the code that worked for me is this: `awk -v str=$CHK" '$0 != str' ./file > ./file2; mv ./file2 ./file`.  This is what worked.

Comment: Sounds like you tried to let the contents of a shell variable expand to become part of an awk script, don't do that. I showed in my answer how to use a variable and provided a reference for more information - `awk -v str="$CHK" '$0 != str' sample`

Comment: Don't do `whatever ./file > ./file2; mv ./file2 ./file` or it'll trash your input file on a failure, do `whatever ./file > ./file2 && mv ./file2 ./file` instead. Updating the input file is a separate issue from what you asked about though, covered in many answers.

Comment: Yup. That did the trick!  And if I want to re-write the same file, I simply send the output to a secondary file, then perform a mv from the secondary file to the primary file.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: TBH, I was trying to do something too complicated for the `perl -i -nle` command. many help sites (like this one) often had warnings about the caveats using this specific command.  The `awk` command works much better.  Again...THANK YOU!!!

Comment: You're welcome. FYI GNU awk has `-i inplace` to do the same thing that `-i` does for `perl` or `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with python too apart from shell and perl based commands.

```
data = ["temp1", "temp1.1", "temp1.2", "temp2", "another_temp1.1"]
filtered_data = [item for item in data if "temp1" not in item]
print(filtered_data)`
```

Output will be:
['temp1.1', 'temp1.2', 'other_temp', 'another_temp1.1']

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*via Raku's `m/…/` match operator:*

```
~$ raku -ne '.put unless m/^ tmp1 $/;' sample.txt > tmp

#OR:

~$ raku -e 'for lines() {.put unless m/^ tmp1 $/};' sample.txt > tmp
```

*via Raku's `grep`:*

```
~$ raku -e 'given lines() {.grep(none /^ tmp1 $/).join("\n").put };' sample.txt > tmp
```

*via Raku's `S///` "big-S" substitution operator:*

```
~$ raku -e 'for lines.join("\n") {S:g/ [[^ | ^^] tmp1 $$ \n] | [\n ^^ tmp1 $] //.put};'   sample.txt > tmp
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family that provides high-level support for Unicode, built-in. Above are four answers showing that like Perl itself--TMTOWTDI applies.

As mentioned in other answers, the key here is using zero-width anchors such as: `^` start-of-string, `$` end-of-string, `^^` start-of-line, `$$` end-of-line. More Regex advice at the bottom links.

Sample Input:

```
tmp2
tmp3
tmp0
tmp1
tmp3
tmp3
tmp3
tmp1.1
tmp3
tmp2
tmp3
tmp1.2
tmp4
```

Sample Output:

```
tmp2
tmp3
tmp0
tmp3
tmp3
tmp3
tmp1.1
tmp3
tmp2
tmp3
tmp1.2
tmp4
```

Note: the code examples above work even if the target string occupies a final line not terminated by a `\n` newline. Since [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) defines a line as `\n` newline terminated, you can correct the final line by using `slurp()` instead of `lines.join("\n")` in the final answer above.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes-best-practices
https://raku.org

Answer (score -1):

If possible I would GNU `sed` for that following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
tmp2
tmp3
tmp0
tmp1
tmp3
tmp3
tmp3
tmp1.1
tmp3
tmp2
tmp3
tmp1.2
tmp4
```

then

```
sed '/^tmp1$/d' file.txt
```

gives output

```
tmp2
tmp3
tmp0
tmp3
tmp3
tmp3
tmp1.1
tmp3
tmp2
tmp3
tmp1.2
tmp4
```

Explanation: If line contains startofline followed by tmp1 followed by endofline then `d`elete it (go to next line), otherwise apply default action of printing.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.8)*

If your rules of engagement coerce you to use `perl` AT ANY PRICE then you might do

```
perl -p -0777 -e 's/(?<![^\n])tmp1\n//g' file.txt
```

output is same

*(tested in perl 5, version 34, subversion 0)*

Explanation: `-p -e` engage `sed` mode, `-0777` engage slurp mode (treat whole file as one line), substitute `tmp1\n` if it is not behind non-newline character, this double negation is *not* equivalent to behind newline as former will properly delete `tmp1` in 1st line. **DISCLAIMER** `perl` solution assumes last character of your file is newline, if this does not hold do not use it.